# How to spell "wow"?

Tags: orthographe, anglicismes, interjections, onomatopées

I've read the exclamation "Ouah!" in books, and my dictionaries say it's pronounced, well, like it's spelled. (In English it would be "Ooah!" or "Wa!")

At the same time, I hear the word "wow" a lot in French-language movies and TV, pronounced more or less like the English word, rhyming with "miaou."

Are these considered the same word with different pronunciations? If not, how would "wow" be spelled? Is it considered an Anglicism?

Comment: "Waouh !" ? http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/waouh/186862

Comment: @user5628 trop compliqué à orthographer... =/

Answer (score 6):

En français "Ouah!" se prononce *ou* diphtongue *a* :  il est aussi à la mode d'utiliser le *W* anglais pour labialiser le *ou* en *wou*, mais pas l'anglais "Ooah!" : *O* diphtongue *a*  peut s'entendre parfois, mais n'est pas d'un usage courant.

Le *wow* (*[w]ou* diphtongue *o*, parfois *wo*) est un héritage des séries et usages américains, et doit être considéré comme un anglicisme (peu de *w* dans les dictionnaires français, alors deux *w* dans le même mot !), aucun exemple dans la littérature française, à moins que cette dernière rapporte des propos d'une langue étrangère.

Ces deux termes sont des interjections strictement identiques et interchangeables ; certains puristes rattacheront *wow* à un type de dialogue, à un type d'ambiance ou à un milieu particulier, mais cela demeure très subjectif.

---

> **W** : vingt-troisième lettre et dix-huitième consonne de l'alphabet (prise aux langues germaniques au Moyen Âge), *présente dans les emprunts* à l'anglais, à l'allemand et aux langues slaves. – Le Robert

Ce n'est donc pas une lettre d'origine française ; j'ai compté moins de quatre-vingt mots commençant par *W* dans le Robert sur les 60 000 annoncés.